# How to erase PolyLine in Google Map..?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, polyline

First, i'm sorry about my English.
I created the app for detecting walking and tracking step. Tracking step is good. But problem is that the app redetecting steps, Doesn't erase before polyline.
I try to map.clear(), polyline.remove()... etc. But Doesn't activate.

this is my source for draw polyline

```
polyline = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
polylineOptions.width(5);
polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

this places onLocationListener in LocationListener.
location is onLocationListener's parameter.

How to remove previous polylines...? 
Im sorry about my English. Please Help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what  kind of veriable is polyline ?

Answer (score 1):

To remove polyline.

```
//Adds the line to map
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
//removes the same line from map
line.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But line'remove is that i already use method. That's not operated.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Shapes documentation specifically on [Remove a Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polyline_remove), call the setMap() method passing null as the argument to remove a polyline from the map.

How to do it is also shown in Remove a Polyline [sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-remove).